# Using the Group filter with Squarebit Charge plugin

Tags: plugin-charge, group

Has anyone had success using the Group filter with Squarebit Charge?

I tried a few different approaches, in each case getting array errors. Here is code:

```
{% set allCharges = craft.charge.charges.limit(3)|group('cardName') %}
```

{% for cardName, details in allCharges %}

```
{{ cardName }}

{% for details in allCharges %} 
    {{ details.dateCreated }}...and more fields
{% endfor %}
```

{% endfor %}

This throws an error message *"Key "dateCreated" for array with keys "0" does not exist."*

If I dump(details) I see an array that looks like all the fields you would expect, including "dateCreated"

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a certain reason why you loop twice?

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work with the following:

```
{% set allCharges = craft.charge.charges.limit(5) %}
{% set charges = allCharges|group("dateCreated|date('F')") %}

{% for month, details in charges %}
    <div>   
        {{ month }}

        {% for detail in details %}
            <p>{{detail.id}}{{detail.customerName}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Two things to note: the group filter was applied to the results of the Charges query, rather than applying it to the query itself; the second issue is that the Charge model contains sub-models,which will require an inner loop.